# Spark code to group integers in buckets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'd like a function that a column and a list of bucket ranges as arguments and returns the appropriate bucket.  I want to solve this with the Spark API and don't want to use a UDF.

Let's say we start with this DataFrame (`df`):

```
+--------+
|some_num|
+--------+
|       3|
|      24|
|      45|
|    null|
+--------+
```

Here's the desired behavior of the function:

```
df.withColumn(
  "bucket",
  bucketFinder(
    col("some_num"),
    Array(
      (0, 10),
      (10, 20),
      (20, 30),
      (30, 70)
    )
  )
).show()

+--------+------+
|some_num|bucket|
+--------+------+
|       3|  0-10|
|      24| 20-30|
|      45| 30-70|
|    null|  null|
+--------+------+
```

Here is the code I tried that does not work:

```
def bucketFinder(col: Column, buckets: Array[(Any, Any)]): Column = {

  buckets.foreach { res: (Any, Any) =>
    when(col.between(res._1, res._2), lit(s"$res._1 - $res._2"))
  }

}
```

It's pretty easy to write this code with a UDF, but hard when constrained to only the Spark API.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the column by 10 and then the `floor` and `ceil` of the column should make the *bucket* you need:

```
val bucket_size = 10    
val floor_col = floor(df("some_num") / bucket_size) * bucket_size

df.withColumn("bucket", concat_ws("-", floor_col, floor_col + bucket_size)).show
+--------+------+
|some_num|bucket|
+--------+------+
|       3|  0-10|
|      24| 20-30|
```

For a bucket size of 5:

```
val bucket_size1 = 5
val floor_col = floor(df("some_num") / bucket_size1) * bucket_size1

df.withColumn("bucket", concat_ws("-", floor_col, floor_col + bucket_size1)).show
+--------+------+
|some_num|bucket|
+--------+------+
|       3|   0-5|
|      24| 20-25|
```

Comment: It looks like he may want a more generalized solution, with the ability to pass in arbitrarily sized buckets.

Comment: @TravisHegner Added a variant that should work on a different bucket size as well.

Comment: @Psidom - I'd ideally like a solution that would work for different sized buckets... sorry for not specifying that clearly in the question

Comment: @Powers Do you mean you could have buckets like `0-5, 5-15, 15-25` etc, i.e. the distances are different for different bucket ?

Comment: @Psidom - Yep, that's right, I updated the question with better data to illustrate the need.  Thanks!

Comment: @Powers You might use [spark.ml.feature.bucketizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#bucketizer)

Comment: @Psidom - check out the answer I added and let me know what you think ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure Spark solution:

```
def bucketFinder(col: Column, buckets: Array[(Any, Any)]): Column = {

  val b = buckets.map { res: (Any, Any) =>
    when(col.between(res._1, res._2), lit(s"${res._1}-${res._2}"))
  }

  coalesce(b: _*)

}
```

I'll leave this question open for a bit to see if someone else has a more elegant solution.